# Data Grid View Selection c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

Recently I made the 2048 game using a DataGridView. Everything works except for the blue selection/focus that appears on the DataGrid when my form starts and I use the arrow keys. I tried to remove it with ClearSelection(), works except for the arrows. How could I disable the blue selected cell? How can I disable the arrows?

```
public Form1_Load (......)
{    
DataGridView1.ClearSelection();
}
```

Image Link (I need more reputation to upload it on the site)

http://s23.postimg.org/beekn9i6z/Immagine.png

Screenshot of Datagrid during Runtime

http://s1.postimg.org/s5loh0uvj/datagrid.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handling selection in form load is too early because form is not shown yet. Perform datagridview clear selection in form shown event.

```
 private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           DataGridView1.ClearSelection();
    }
```

OR

```
 void dataGridView2_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView2.ClearSelection();
    }
```

Comment: Can you add screenshot in your question?

Comment: Actually I meant the screen shot of datagridview actually.

Comment: Ok, Now there's the screenshot of the form with the blue selection I need to remove. When I use an arrow the blue selection compares. To play I'm using ASDW

Comment: So you have tried on `Form1_Shown` and result was not working?

Comment: Yes, I tried but I have the same problem. Maybe the best solution is to disable the arrows but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Selected = false;
```

Comment: Sid? Your question appears as "Low Quality". You may include some comments or explanation, event it is relevant.